# Switching to OOP from Procedural style and MySQLi

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

How can I extend / include another class that does some of the database querying?

In the method "getAccount", I want to call a certain method in class "UserQueries" which would send back an array of user data.

I should ask as well, when moving to OOP; should there be a class for each type of mysqli interaction?

Right now (procedural) I have a file called "functions.php" and it is getting very large and gross.

```
class AccountManager {

private $type = ""; //user type
private $id = 0; //user id

private $user; //array of users info
private $tmpID; //tmpID that is sent in

public $success;

public function __construct($uid) {
    //passed in userID
    $this->tmpID = $uid;
    $this->success = null;
    self::getAccount();
}

public function __destruct() {
}

protected function getAccount() {
    //$this->user = UserQueries::get_user_by_id($this->tmpID);
    //get_user_by_id will return an array
    //Example of what would be returned
    $this->user = ["1", 'someuser', "101"];
    if($this->user) {
        $this->success = self::setAccount();
    } else {
        $this->success = false;
    }
}

private function setAccount() { ....
//more logic
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In general there are a few different ways to think about it.  You can create "Data Access Objects", you could have each object know how to read/write themselves from the database, you could have an object wrap the database connection, or you could use a framework or ORM that does the database stuff for you.  These are design questions that lead this question toward being potentially off-topic as a "which is the best solution" type question.